# Combining Toggle and Click functions with JQuery

Tags: jquery, click, hover, toggle

I have a slideshow gallery on my site.  There's a script from a JQuery plugin that i'm using that performs some functions when i click on the anchor.  What i am wanting to do is see if i can make the pause button change to the hover state when it is clicked and then if it is clicked again change back to the normal state.

I tried doing this by just saying if the img.src == the normal state then change it to the hover state when clicked.  The of course didn't work because when you hover over it, it is no longer on the normal state.  Hope that makes sense.  here's my code:

```
<a id="galleryPause" href="#">
<img src="images/galleryPause.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/galleryPauseHover.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/galleryPause.jpg'" style="margin-left:-4px;" />
</a>
```

I basically want to keep the existing hover functionality and add a click functionality to it that changes the default image to the hover state and back.  This is so that the user knows that the gallery is paused.  Thanks for any help with this!

**UPDATE:**
This is the code for the plugin i am using.  Is there a way i can hijack this code to get it to do what i'm wanting?

Plugin script link:  http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js

Code in the `<head>...</head>` of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var autoPlayTime=5000;
    autoPlayTimer = setInterval( autoPlay, autoPlayTime);
    function autoPlay(){
        Slidebox('next');
    }
    $('#bannerWrapper .thumbs .next').click(function () {
        Slidebox('next','next');
    });
    $('#bannerWrapper .thumbs .previous').click(function () {
        Slidebox('previous','next');
    });
});
//slide page to id
function Slidebox(slideTo,autoPlay){
    var animSpeed=1000; //animation speed
    var easeType='easeInOutExpo'; //easing type
    var sliderWidth=$('#bannerWrapper').width();
    var leftPosition=$('#bannerWrapper .container').css("left").replace("px", "");
    $("#bannerWrapper .content").each(function (i) {
        totalContent=i*sliderWidth; 
        $('#bannerWrapper .container').css("width",totalContent+sliderWidth);
    });
    if( !$("#bannerWrapper .container").is(":animated")){
        if(slideTo=='next'){ //next
            if(autoPlay=='stop'){
                clearInterval(autoPlayTimer);
            }
            if(leftPosition==-totalContent){
                $('#bannerWrapper .container').animate({left: 0}, animSpeed, easeType); //reset
            } else {
                 $('#bannerWrapper .container').animate({left: '-='+sliderWidth}, animSpeed, easeType); //next
            }
        } else if(slideTo=='previous'){ //previous
            if(autoPlay=='stop'){
                clearInterval(autoPlayTimer);
            }
            if(leftPosition=='0'){
                $('#bannerWrapper .container').animate({left: '-'+totalContent}, animSpeed, easeType); //reset
            } else {
                $('#bannerWrapper .container').animate({left: '+='+sliderWidth}, animSpeed, easeType); //previous
            }
        } else {
            var slide2=(slideTo-1)*sliderWidth;
            if(leftPosition!=-slide2){
                clearInterval(autoPlayTimer);
                $('#bannerWrapper .container').animate({left: -slide2}, animSpeed, easeType); //go to number
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you track a separate "is clicked" state in your code, you can use that to determine the click status, rather than trying to hijack the hover state status. Then when hovering, you can check if the gallery has been clicked. If so, bypass the normal hover event, until a future click occurs. So the click state would pause / resume the slideshow.

Comment: Yea...i've been trying to figure out the code for the click function already existing on it and have been unsuccessful so far.  I will update the post with the code for the plugin as well.

Comment: Is the gallery dynamically created? If so, have you tried ('#bannerWrapper .thumbs .next').live("click", ... rather than ('#bannerWrapper .thumbs .next').click()?

Comment: yes...the gallery is populated dynamically using JSON.  What would that change allow me to do?

Comment: click() will only hook into things in your DOM upon the first HTTP request. live() will hook into any elements added into the DOM after the initial HTTP load. See http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Cool...i'll have to check that out.  Any thoughts on my initial question for the pause button?  Or is this what you're talking about with "live"?

Comment: I think that may be one way to approach your requirement. If you capture the click events using live (and hover events with live as well perhaps?), then it may work for what you need it to. You could keep track of your click state in a variable or something, and handle accordingly

Comment: i'll check that out.  I do like the idea of the variable.  Thanks for the help and ideas!